# Scheme: Program to iterate through a list and return only the non-numbers

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I'm trying to write a program in Scheme that takes a list and returns a list of only the non-number items in it.  This seems like it should work but it is only printing the entire list.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

```
;;;up-to-first-number
;;;takes a list as its input and returns a list containing all
;;;the elements up to the first numeric element in the input list.

;;test lists
(define mylist '(a b c 1 2 3))
(define mylist2 '(1 2 2 4 5))


    (define (up-to-first-number list)
      (cond
       ((null? list)'())  ;if list is null, return null list
       ((number? list) '())  ;if item is a number, return null list
       (else (cons (car list) (up-to-first-number (cdr list)))) )) ;else, add item to new list and recurse
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second condition is wrong:

```
((number? list) '())
```

You don't test the list with `number?`, you should test `(car list)`, and recursively process `(cdr list)` if the head element is a number. Check out the following code:

```
(define (up-to-first-number lst)
(cond
 ((null? lst) '())
 ((number? (car lst)) (up-to-first-number (cdr lst)))
 (else (cons (car lst) (up-to-first-number (cdr lst))))))
```

Comment: That was it!   car list instead of just list.  Such a simple fix.  Thank you!!

Comment: Glad to help:-) I'll appreciate if you can accept it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

With such an easy procedure you should be able to deduct by hand..

```
(up-to-first-number '(1)) ; ==

(cond
  ((null? '(1)) '())
  ((number? '(1)) '())
  (else (cons (car '(1)) (up-to-first-number (cdr '(1))))))
```

So `(null? '(1))` is `#f` as expected, but you might be surprised `(number? '(1))` is `#f` too? Perhaps your bug is there somewhere.

Also note that by calling your argument `list` the standard procedure `list` is no longer available in that procedure. That's why you often see `lst` be used to denote list argument in Scheme code.